# rust receive messages from multiple channels at once

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a `Vec<tokio::sync::broadcast::Receiver<String>>` (basically a vector of channel receivers). I want to subscribe to all of them and get messages from all of them. How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`broadcast::Receiver` is not a stream yet, it's just an object that has a `recv()` function. To combine multiple of them, you have to convert them to streams first.

Luckily, there is the [`tokio-streams`](https://docs.rs/tokio-stream/0.1.11/tokio_stream/wrappers/struct.BroadcastStream.html) crate for just that.

Once the receivers are converted to streams, you can use [`futures::stream::select_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.25/futures/stream/fn.select_all.html) to combine them:

```rust
use futures::stream::select_all;
use futures::StreamExt;
use tokio::time::{sleep, Duration};
use tokio_stream::wrappers::BroadcastStream;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (sender1, receiver1) = tokio::sync::broadcast::channel(5);
    let (sender2, receiver2) = tokio::sync::broadcast::channel(5);

    let receivers = vec![receiver1, receiver2];

    // Send on all channels
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        for i in 0..5 {
            sleep(Duration::from_millis(50)).await;
            sender1.send(format!("A{i}")).unwrap();
            sleep(Duration::from_millis(50)).await;
            sender2.send(format!("B{i}")).unwrap();
        }
    });

    // Receive on all channels simultaneously
    let mut fused_streams = select_all(receivers.into_iter().map(BroadcastStream::new));
    while let Some(value) = fused_streams.next().await {
        println!("Got value: {}", value.unwrap());
    }
}
```

```
Got value: A0
Got value: B0
Got value: A1
Got value: B1
Got value: A2
Got value: B2
Got value: A3
Got value: B3
Got value: A4
Got value: B4
```